# A Streamlined Way to Export / Import Entries Between Environments?

Tags: entries, plugins, import, export

Do any of you have a preferred workflow for exporting entries to be imported into another installation of Craft using plugins or migrations or other processes? I'd think this would be a good job for a plugin, but I'm also curious what works for other Craft users.

**Plugins That Work Well with Feed Me?**

It seems that [Feed Me](https://plugins.craftcms.com/feed-me) is the de facto solution for importing as it's been absorbed into Craft, but is there a specific plugin or method that works well with that plugin for exporting?

The most actively maintained export plugin I've found is "[craft-export-csv](https://github.com/kffein/Craft-export-Csv)," but it's a paid plugin that hasn't seen any maintenance since last April, and I'm wary to build a process around a plugin that could see deprecation.

**Alternate Plugins?**

Beyond something that can be chained into Feed Me, is there an all-in-one solution, like [Field Manager](https://plugins.craftcms.com/field-manager) for exporting fields? Nothing seems to come up when searching the Plugin Store.

If nothing exists out there that fits this criteria, I'd be down to start working on something like this on my own, as it'd save me and my coworkers potentially hours of copying / pasting fields between environments.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do to solve this problem: [Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms)

I've found that this KISS technique of just declaring one environment as the "gold master" and pulling changes to all other environments works really well for me.